# xslt 1.0 and conditional 404 error message

Tags: xslt, error-handling

I wonder if I can do this in xslt 1.0.

if page > totalpages display the standard 404 error page.
Or is the only way to make a custom 404 error page.

Roelof

Comment: "page > totalpages" are these inputs to your XSL transform?

Comment: yep, page is the current page and totalpages are the total of pages needed to display all articles of a categorie

Comment: There is no such thing as a "standard 404 error page". 404 is an HTTP response code. You can always generate a page which looks the same as the page you see on a 404 error, but from XSLT itself you can't control the HTTP response code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT is a transform language for taking an XML document and transforming it into another XML (or text) document. It is not an appropriate tool for specifying website navigation, with XSLT you will not be able to specify the HTTP response code.

Comment: that would make much more sense. A 404 is something that should be handled by your web application framework. This will ensure that it is served with the correct response code.